# When submitting an iOS app to iTunesConnect for internal testing, do I need distribution a certificate

Tags: ios, xcode

When submitting an iOS app to iTunesConnect for internal testing, do I need distribution a certificate or development certificate?

I want to use PushNotification so I want to know if I have to configure certificate for distribution, or development is enought for internal testers.

Comment: You will need Distribution/Production certificate also in TestFlight if you want your testers receive Push Notifications

Comment: I need BOTH certificates? for internal testers??

Comment: For Push Notifications only with production certificate is enought. Development one is only for developing devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a distribution certificate *and* an AppStore provisioning profile. From the [TestFlight Beta Testing documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH35):

> **Important**:  In order to use iTunes Connect for TestFlight beta testing, you must submit your app using the latest App Store Distribution profiles that contain the beta entitlement. To regenerate your App Store distribution profile, visit the Member Center; read [Beta Testing Your iOS App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH8) in [*App Distribution Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582).